$\mathbb P_{x_0}(\tau>t\mid X_1=x_1)=\mathbb P_{x_0}(\tau>t)$
Let $(\Omega,F,\mathbb P_x,(Y_t)_{t\geq 0})_{x\in E}$ be a continuous time Markov chain with countable state space $E$. I found the following identity on page 73 of Liggett's introduction to Continuous Time Markov Processes ($\tau_n$ is the time of the n-th transition and $X_n$ is the state in between $\tau_n$ and $\tau_{n+1}$):
\begin{equation}
\mathbb P_{x_0}(X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_n=x_n,\tau_1>t_1,\ldots,\tau_{n+1}>t_{n+1})=p(x_0,x_1)\cdots p(x_{n-1},x_n)\exp(-c(x_0)t_1)\cdots\exp(-c(x_n)t_{n+1})
\end{equation}
It is not clear to me how this follows from the Markov property. I am especially interested in the case $n=1$, $t_2=0$:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb P_{x_0}(X_1=x_1,\tau_1>t_1)=p(x_0,x_1)\exp(-c(x_0)t_1)
\end{equation}
Since $p(x_0,x_1)=\mathbb P_{x_0}(X_1=x_1)$ and $\exp(-c(x_0)t_1)=\mathbb P_{x_0}(\tau_1>t_1)$, we obtain
\begin{equation}
\mathbb P_{x_0}(\tau>t\mid X_1=x_1)=\mathbb P_{x_0}(\tau>t),
\end{equation}
where $\tau$ is the time of the first jump.
If someone can explain how to derive the first equation, or at least this special case, that would be much appreciated.
